# Qt: Display Live Video, One Frame At A Time

Tags: c++, qt

I have a decoded video frame coming over a distributed bus.  Currently, I am using a QLabel that receives the frame buffer via `Qt Signal/Slot` and sets it's pixmap.

```
void VideoViewer::slot_update_view( unsigned char* frame, QSize size )
{
        QImage img( frame, size.width(), size.height(), QImage::Format_RGB888 );
        _label->setPixmap( QPixmap::fromImage( img ).scaledToWidth( width(), Qt::SmoothTransformation ) );
}
```

This works, but using QLabel feels hacky. Is there a better solution?  Eventually I'd like to draw on top of the video.

Comment: You could create a widget which just draws the image, probably using OpenGL (easy with Qt) to improve perf, and also quality if you need scaling.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, the best way to make it less 'hacky' and more robust is to use some low-level image classes instead of raw pointers to buffers. For example, you could use a representation like the [one in *OpenCV*](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html?highlight=mat).

Using plain buffers can be really risky, and bugs will be hard to track.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Roman. The char* has already been decoded and checked. I'm really just interested in the best method of display, preferable within Qt.

Comment: Yes, but there is a risk that it can be broken. Encapsulating all the image attributes inside a single structure seems like a more reliable solution.